# Batch Reading a Result Set from a SQL Server Sproc with a very large amount of data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, ado.net, export

I'm attempting to perform a data export using .NET code from SQL Server. I have the bulk of the export logic inside of a stored procedure that's returning a resultset with `FOR JSON AUTO` to export data. The Stored Proc builds the JSON result exactly as I need it and my .NET code essentially just needs to consume that Stored Proc and put the results to an FTP location. This works great for most of my exports.

The problem is that some exports have a large amount of data with the resulting JSON file being hundreds of megabytes (and it **will** be gigabytes). I'm running into issues where I start to get `OutOfMemeoryExceptions` being thrown because of how I handle this data (i.e. storing it all in memory within .NET both inside of a DataTable that I fill and then later into a StringBuilder). While I have temporarily thrown more money/memory at the problem, this isn't a scalable solution.

So I clearly need to change strategies, which is fine since my current process is not terribly well-optimized. The most obvious counter-strategy is then to use a `SqlDataReader` and call `while (reader.Read())` and push it to a temp file on disk (to later stream to an FTP). And technically, this approach works since I don't really need to "intelligently process" the recordset - just store it and ship it. But `reader.Read()` will just get 1 record at a time (which, with `FOR JSON AUTO` this is more than 1 record but is still quite tiny compared to hundreds of megabytes). The problem with this approach is that the tiny size of the data payloads here are really **way too small** and this makes way too many round-trips to the database which results in this export simply being too slow. I normally optimize with *chunky over chatty* and this option is simply too *chatty* but the way I'm doing it today is too *chunky*.

Is there something in between those two options? I'd LOVE if I could do the `SqlDataReader` but tell it to batch it into 1000 records per round-trip to the database since these network round-trips are what are killing me with this counter-strategy. Alternatively, if there was some way I could control the size of the records when from the `FOR JSON AUTO` recordset to be much larger than they currently are (8k? I forget), that might be an option as well.

I have Entity Framework in my solution although I'm dropping down to ADO.NET for my current code. I would be willing to include another frameworks if that's necessary. But a simple ADO.NET solution would be ideal.

Comment: I had similar issue.  What I did was run the SQL Server utility SQLCMD (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine).  I the output the result to a CSV file and imported the CSV into my c# appl.  To automate the entire task I used a BackGroundProcessor (to prevent the application from locking up) and launched a Process from c# that called the SQLCMD query.  SQLCMD is meant as an archive tool for SQL server and runs much quicker that queiries from c# and works with very large databases.

Comment: @jdweng Unfortunately this isn't an option for me. This is operating in Azure against Azure SQL Database with everything hosted as PaaS (i.e. no VMs). While this would be a great option with some on-prem or IaaS hosting, it would require too much new infrastructure for me to consider.

Comment: I think the timing issue is between the PaaS and the SQL database.Straight queries will always be slow.I think the is the bottle-neck and nothing that you can do will bypass the bottle-neck. Using ADO.Net I suspect you have a direct connection to the database bypassing the PaaS.  If that is the case then you should also be able to use SQLCMD.exe.SQLCMD does not require any license.You need to install SQL Server Management Studio [SSMS] (also no license required) on local PC. SSMS will allow you to directly connect to database bypassing the bottle-neck just like you would be doing with ADO.Net.

Comment: I'm sorry but as I stated before, that requires more infrastructure than I'm willing to or capable of managing. This isn't a 1-time thing. This runs anywhere from multiple times every 5 minutes to daily (and everywhere in between). I phrased this question in a very specific way - I'm not looking to re-architecture my infrastructure to avoid finding an answer to my question. I appreciate the help and suggestion, but it doesn't answer this question.

Comment: I understand.  Just don't think there is any workable solution except to bypass PaaS.  Don't think my solution is major re-architecture.   It is basically one SQL Query direct to database than to go through PaaS.  The reading CSV is simple.  Splitting on commas will give same fields as you original method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it may not be a perfect solution, this is the implementation I went with:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Calls a stored procedure that returns data as "FOR JSON AUTO" and stores the results into a temporary file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connection">SQLConnection to execute the stored procedure on.</param>
    /// <param name="commandTextForJsonQuery">CommandText for the execution.</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">All input and output parameters.</param>
    /// <param name="optionalFilePathAndName">
    ///     Optional file name and path to write to. If not specified, a Temp file will be created.
    ///     If specified but the file does not exist, the file will be created. If it exists, it will first be deleted and all
    ///     contents will be lost.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="commandTimeoutInSeconds">CommandTimeout to use with execution.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the filename and path with the data in it.</returns>
    private static async Task<string> CallJsonQueryAndSaveToFile(SqlConnection connection, string commandTextForJsonQuery, SqlParameter[] parameters, string optionalFilePathAndName, int commandTimeoutInSeconds)
    {
        var needsToCloseConnection = false;
        optionalFilePathAndName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(optionalFilePathAndName)
                                      ? Path.GetTempFileName()
                                      : optionalFilePathAndName;

        if (File.Exists(optionalFilePathAndName))
        {
            File.Delete(optionalFilePathAndName);
        }

        using (var file = File.AppendText(optionalFilePathAndName))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandTextForJsonQuery, connection)
                                 {
                                     CommandTimeout = commandTimeoutInSeconds,
                                     CommandType = CommandType.Text
                                 })
            {
                command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

                try
                {
                    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        needsToCloseConnection = true;
                        connection.Open();
                    }

                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            await file.WriteAsync(reader.GetString(0));
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (needsToCloseConnection)
                    {
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return optionalFilePathAndName;
    }
}
```

An example of the commandTextForJsonQuery in my case:

```
var cmdText = "EXEC @procResult = [dbo].[spFoo] @Param1, @Param2, @Param3"
```

This implementation seems to run much faster than I had expected. While I haven't heavily tested it when hosted in Azure, while testing it locally I'm able to saturate my 200mbps ISP connection, which is good enough for me. I don't need this to be perfectly optimized, just "optimized enough" so it doesn't take forever to execute.